# Unexpected Regular expression result using dot symbol

Tags: nginx, lua, lua-patterns

I'm tring to detect file format: for instanse 23.ts

if I use `string.match( entities[3], 'ts$' ) -- returns ts`

if I use `string.match( entities[3], '\.ts$' ) --returns error`

if I use `string.match( entities[3], '\\.ts$' ) --returns nil`

if I use `string.match( entities[3], '[\\.]{1}ts$' ) --returns nil`

if I use `string.match( entities[3], '.ts$' ) --works`

for all strings like ats, bts, cts ...
WHY? How can I detect `.` symbol?

Comment: lua pattern escape is `%`. See [5.4.1 - Patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `.` with `%.`.